# Visualforce chart Custom field filter error: For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because XXX is not valid

Tags: visualforce, reporting, visualforce-charting, analytics-reportchart

HEELP! I have a report for opportunities. I need a VF that shows this report and I need a filter using a custom field named: PUBLISH DATE(Publish_Date__c   ) :

[image]

I've tried Publish_Date__c, Publish_Date, PUBLISH_DATE__C, PUBLISH_DATE and it doesnt work (if I try with standard fields like 'CREATED_DATE', 'CLOSE_DATE, STAGE_NAME' it works).

Is it not 'Publish_Date__c' the API name? If 'Publish_Date__c' is not the API name (in that case it is weird because the definition of the field says "API NAME: Publish_Date__c") how can I get the API name?

This is the code I wrote:

```
  <apex:page >
      <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oc00X0000HT0q"
                           hideonerror="false"
                           filter="[{column:'Publish_Date__c,operator:'equals',value:'2016-12-12'}]"
                           size="small"></analytics:reportChart>

    </apex:page>
```

the error I got:

[image]

Comment: Create a report with that filter, then pull down the metadata and examine it. That will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Thank you for your replaying, but I am a little new in salesforce... you said: "Create a report with that filter", is the report of opportunity  that I have already created Isnt it? and what do you mean by pull down the metada?

Answer (score 0):

From the Custom Field Definition Detail page, click on "View Field Accessibility" and check to make sure it's not set to "Hidden" for your Profile. Update as necessary, then retry. If you've made the field visible but are getting the same error, the next thing to check is if the report that you're using is based on a Custom Report Type. Navigate to ####.salesforce.com/00Oc00X0000HT0q (Replace the #### with your instance) then click "Customize" and in the far upper left hand corner look at the "Report Type:" and make note of the name. Next, navigate to Setup > Create > Report Types then see if a label matches. If it does click on the LABEL NAME (not on Edit) scroll to the bottom and click "Edit Layout." On the far right there's a box with a "View:" picklist, select "Opportunity Fields" click "Next Page" until you find "Publish Date" then drag it from the box on the right to the "Opportunities" section to the left.

EDIT: In addition to the above items, depending on where this is being used you may need:
    filter="[{column:'Opportunity.Publish_Date__c'

Comment: Hi Clark. I checked the visibility and accesibility, is not Hidden. The problem continues. Regarding your 2nd solution, the report type I'm using for my created report is the Standar: Opportunity (only opportunity) so my report does not exist in "Setup>Create>Report Types" (that is for custom report types), so Is it mandatory to use custom report type and follow your instructions for adding a chart with filter in mi VF?  Anyway, I created a custom report type, I followed your instructions dragging the field in Edit Layout, I created a report based on that custom report and the error continues.

Comment: If you're using a standard report type the field would automatically show up; there's no need to create a custom report type. did you try adding "Opportunity.Publish_Date__c" to this:                            filter="[{column:'Opportunity.Publish_Date__c,operator:'equals',value:'2016-12-12'}]"

Comment: Let me see If I understood: what you said: If I'm using a standard report type, the field should be automatically show up,  where it should appear automatically? do you mean In the navigation menu that you suggested  "Setup>Create>Report Types" ? (There only appear a list of custom report types, there is not my standard report type, so I created a custom report type for following your instrucions and test). Or do you mean that the field should show up in my visualforce without problem if I use the filter propperty ( because is not happening, actually is my problem, SF doesnt reconignizes it).

Comment: It would show up in the native report viewer/editor: If you go back to ####.salesforce.com/00Oc00X0000HT0q (Replace the #### with your instance) then click "Customize" in the list of the fields on the left-hand side it would automatically show up in Standard Reports.  Have you tried adding "Opportunity." before the "Publish_Date__c" in your code? It would be: Opportunity.Publish_Date__c